# How to create a column in SQL containing using the AVG() function?

Tags: sql

I have a table with one column and 46 rows and I want to create another column that contains the average of the first column in all 46 rows
e.g.
This is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE table2
SELECT column1 
FROM table1
```

I want to add another column that contains for each row (46 rows) the value of AVG(column1)

How do can it be done?

Comment: I removed the inappropriate database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Don't use a column to store values which are derived from other columns. Use a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't use `create table` to add a column.  In this case, a query using a window function is sufficient:

```
SELECT t1.*, AVG(column1) OVER () as avg_column1
FROM table1 t1;
```

This is Standard SQL and should work in any database.